# Creating new color schemes in brewer.pal

Tags: r, choropleth

When plotting choropleth maps in R, one of the valid color schemes in `brewer.pal` is `RdYlGn`, e.g. I can type `brewer.pal(9, "RdYlGn")`.

I'm looking for the opposite color scheme, where red is used to denote high values and green, low values. However, none of the standard palettes in brewer.pal allow for this. I would try `GnYlRd` if I could, but I get an error message. Neither does the documentation indicate a way to design a custom palette.

What's the easiest way around this?

Comment: Try the reverse function: `myPal<-rev(brewer.pal(9, "RdYlGn"))`

Answer (score 0):

As Dave2e points out, the reverse function `rev(brewer.pal(9, "RdYlGn"))` works.